# What could go wrong updating UI state in this manner

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

**Creating the data class like this:**

```
data class UIState(
    val showCancelDialog: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)
)

//then somewhere in my view side after declaring the uiState
uiState.showCancelDialog.value = true
```

Comment: Need a more info how you have implemented other code.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think there is basically nothing wrong, but it does look a bit odd. You can define the showCancelDialog variable in your view separately and then just use it.

For example:

```
val showCancelDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

ViewState is needed when you change it from viewModel. This is MVI concept. A view sends events (intents) to viewModel, viewModel changes uiState and then the view is updating.

[image]